# How to list nodes that share only the first selected value in an entity reference field?

Tags: 7, views

I have entity reference field to a taxonomy vocabulary on a node, which is a multi value field.

In Views, how do I list related nodes that share only the first selected category?

Example: Suppose I have selected "category3" and "category4" for a node. I want to show other nodes which have selected "category3".

Comment: the first category selected for that node not in the category list. If the selected categories are banana and pear then banana is the first category.
`field_category['und'][0]['target_id'] = 3 (banana id)` and `field_category['und'][1]['target_id'] = 4 (pear id)`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set up something like what you are after with the following steps:

- Create a view of content (nodes)
- Add a contextual filter for NID with a that gets it's default value from "Content ID from url" (presuming the related products are to appear on the original products own page).
- Add a relationship on field_category, call it something like "category", require this relationship
- Add a filter of field_category:delta, value = 0
- Add a relationship of "Content using field_category", require this relationship, use relationship: category, call this relationship something like "related"
- Add another contextual filter that's also for NID with a that gets it's default value from "Content ID from url", use relationship: related, tick "Exclude" in the "More" fieldset at the bottom.
- Now when you add your fields use relationship: related.

Comment: This is not working

Comment: Hi @Ahmad, care to be a bit more specific? What does this output when you try it and how does that differ to what you expect?